# Jpa, how to automatically persist an Entity in case of change in a child entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I'm facing an issue by using jpa.
I have an application with multiple tables / entities, of course, some entities use child entity.
In this application, I have a screen to update the characteristics of a specific product and the name of the customer associated to this product (on another table / entity).

On my product Entity, I have a **OneToOnerelation** to the customer defined like :

```java
 @OneToOne(targetEntity = Customer.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") 
 private Customer customer;
```

In some case, the user only update the customer name and thus, the information is correctly persisted (on table Customer).
But, I want that the record on table Prodcut to be updated too (at least to have the last_updated_date in synch in the database).
As I use the merge command from jpa and the main entity (product) is not updated, it seems, the merge method does nothing.

Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Best regards

Bruno

Comment: just call `persist()` with both objects?

Comment: if i'm not wrong, persist will create (insert) a new record on the database, I need an update.